# How to progammatically subscribe a user on edit form(user_form)using Simiplenews?

Tags: 8, emails

How to programmatically subscribe a user on edit form(user_form)?

I use the code below in `hook_user_presave` after I checked if the user is already subscribed.

```
$subscription_manager = \Drupal::service('simplenews.subscription_manager');
$subscription_manager->subscribe('test@email.com', 'default', FALSE, 'website', 'en');
```

When I go on the **newsletter issues tab** from Content, I did not see the newly subscribers

I have tried turning off setting **Synchronize between account and subscriber fields** on page */admin/config/people/simplenews/settings/subscriber*.

I am using [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) with the 8.6.15 Drupal version.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your code is passing the conditional? Is `default` your news letter's ID?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Also, there's no need to check if a user is already subscribed, Simplenews will happily ignore duplicate subscriptions (but if you're unsubscribing someone, check they are subscribed or it will throw an exception). Have you checked the "Subscribers" tab under "People"?